# Connect to MySQL from WSL2?

Tags: linux, windows, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed MySQL server on Windows and I would like to connect to it from WSL2. Unfortunately it seems that WSL cannot reach the MySQL server:

```
$ /mnt/c/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Server\ 5.7/bin/mysql.exe -uroot -p
Enter password: 
mysql> exit
Bye

$ mysql -uroot -p --protocol=TCP
Enter password: 
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)
```

On `ifconfig` I only have two interfaces `eth0` and `lo`, so it seems WSL and Windows share the same local interface. To verify this I've started a Python webserver and accessed from Windows on localhost.

How to connect to MySQL from WSL2?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [WSL vs WSL2 documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip) on how to connect to the host, you can look in WSL2 in */etc/resolv.conf* for the nameserver, which happens to be the host:

```
export WSL_HOST_IP=$(awk '/nameserver/ { print $2 }' /etc/resolv.conf)
```

Comment: Be aware that it will only work as long as you don't disable the generation of the file.

Comment: Really handy command, not just to connect with MySQL but for many other purposes. 

Comment: You may also need to ensure that whatever port you're connecting to is enabled in your windows firewall. With a warning that there is no [simple] way to distinguish between WSL2 and the outside world..

Comment: I see multiple entries, which are nameservers, not the host.

Answer (score 4):

As described in [this article](https://github.com/mahmoudajawad/wsl-hacks/blob/master/wsl2-networking.md), you have to use the IP that the WSL ethernet adapter creates.

Create the windows firewall rule if necessary. (Inbound rule for MySQL)

Run `ipconfig.exe` and look for `Ethernet-Adapter vEthernet (WSL)`. Extract the IP-Address. (If you use the awk-line from the article, I had to change the $14 to $13 for it to work).

Grant the ip-address access in mysql: `grant all on *.* to 'root'@'172.0.0.0/255.0.0.0' identified by '<password>' with grant option;`
(I found that the IP-Address changes after a Windows restart, therefore I had to use the IP range/mask version.)

Then you can call `mysql -uroot -p -h<ip-address> --protocol=tcp`

**Edit**
If you want to skip this `-h` parameter, you could add the export and an alias to the `.bashrc`:

```
export WSL_HOST_IP=$(/c/Windows/system32/ipconfig.exe | awk '/WSL/ {getline; getline; getline; getline; print substr($13, 1, length($13)-1)}')
alias mysql='mysql -h$WSL_HOST_IP'
```

*(If you use `/mnt/c/` correct the path for ipconfig accordingly.)*

Then you can just type `mysql -uroot ...`

Answer (score 4):

The above steps work, but there is a slightly easier way to refer to the host.

As of 2021,all you need to do is refer to the Windows host as:

```
hostname.
```

or

```
hostname.local
```

This returns the *same* IP address as the brilliant workaround above with the resolve.conf file, and is a little easier.

Note that localhost from wsl does resolve to a different IP, the normal 127.0.0.1

That makes sense, it's a VM, basically.

Unintended consequences: If you're trying to log into say MariaDB, this does not count as localhost - so you have to have the right security setup to allow logging in from a remote machine (the contained VM)